# Swift - IOS : UIalertController position

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to create a custom alertView but i'm facing a problem with the size of the Alert
so my question is :
how could i know the X position of the left corner and the x position of the right corner ?

Comment: `centerInSuperView.x - myOwnWidth / 2.0, centerInSuperView.y - myOwnHeight / 2.0`, or something similar, therefore the right edge's coordinate would be `centerInSuperView.x + myOwnWidth / 2.0` or `myOwnOrigin.x + myOwnWidth` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get x position something like,

```
  x = self.view.frame.size.width/2.0 - yourCustomAlertView.frame.size.width/ 2.0
```

and same for y also,

```
  y = self.view.frame.size.height/2.0 - yourCustomAlertView.frame.size.height/ 2.0
```

**Update :** (As Asked in comment)

You can add `width constraint` same as you have added `height constraint` so your code will be look like,

```
    var height:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200);

    var width : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 300);

    alertController.view.addConstraint(height);

     alertController.view.addConstraint(width);
```

Comment: in fact it doesn't work also, i know my height is 200, however when i use your Y, the output is 0, which means that the alert and the viewController have same height, which is not true

Comment: are you using autolayout ?

Comment: is there anyway to set the width of the alert ?

Comment: which alert ? native alert which we get by `UIALertController` ? or customized (i mean by using uiview)?

Comment: i mean, i could make the height as 200 by using this line of code :  var height:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200); and then i       alertController.view.addConstraint(height);

__so is there anyway to make the same for the width ?

Comment: add width constraint same as you have add height constraint!

Answer (score 0):

You can access properties on the frame of the view. `alertView.frame.minX` will get you the left corner X and `alertView.frame.maxX` will get you the right corner X.

Comment: i tried that, but it always gives me 0 and 375.0, however if i do the same for my Screen i have the same output (0 and 375.0 ) where it's very clear that the width of the alertView is smaller that Screen

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: i'm using these 2 lines of codes   
var height:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)
        

   var width:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: viewController.view.frame.width * 0.4)